# How to simulate data from Gumbel Bivariate Exponential Distribution

Tags: r

I am working on a paper and want to simulate data from Gumbel bivariate exponential distribution type I and type II.

Here's the Gumbel Bivariate distribution:
[image: Here's the pdf of Gumbel Bivariate distribution]

I tried using the `rgumbel` function from the `Gumbel` package, but the package considers `lambda1 = lambda2 = 1`, but in my case, I want to consider different lambda values.

Also, I tried implementing the inverse CDF uniform sampling approach with the marginals but did not work because the marginals consider correlation=0.

Kindly assist if there is an R package on that or if not, what is the concept behind simulating data from the bivariate exponential distribution from scratch in R?

Answer (score 2):

The distribution of `x2` conditioned on `x1` is a gamma mixture with shape parameters 1 and 2 and weights and a common rate parameter that are a function of `x1` and the GBVE parameters. A scheme for sampling is then

1. Sample `x1` from its marginal
2. Sample `x2` conditioned on `x1`

Implemented in a function (you may want to check my algebra):

```
rGBVE <- function(n, lambda1, lambda2, theta) {
  x1 <- rexp(n, lambda1)
  lambda12 <- lambda1*lambda2
  pprod <- lambda12*theta
  C <- exp(lambda1*x1)
  A <- (lambda12 - pprod + pprod*lambda1*x1)/C
  B <- (pprod*lambda2 + pprod^2*x1)/C
  D <- lambda2 + pprod*x1
  wExp <- A/D
  wGamma <- B/D^2
  data.frame(x1, x2 = rgamma(n, (runif(n) > wExp/(wExp + wGamma)) + 1, D))
}
```

This will return `n` samples in a `data.frame`.

**UPDATE**

To arrive at this solution, notice that when `x1` is given, the density function can be written in the form `(A + B*x2)/exp(logC + D*x2) = (A + B*x2)/(C*exp(D*x2)) = A/(C*D)*D*exp(-D*x2) + B/(C*D^2)*D^2*x2*exp(-D*x2)`, where `A`, `B`, `logC`, `C`, and `D` are constant for a given `x1`.

`D*exp(-D*x2)` is the PDF of an exponential distribution with a rate parameter equal to `D` (or a gamma distribution with a shape parameter equal to 1 and rate parameter equal to `D`). `D^2*x2*exp(-D*x2)` is the PDF of a gamma distribution with shape parameter equal to 2 and a rate parameter equal to `D`. `A/(C*D)` and `B/(C*D^2)` are the relative weights of the mixture distribution.

I double-checked my algebra, and I believe it is correct. The function can be streamlined a bit:

```
rGBVE <- function(n, lambda1, lambda2, theta) {
  x1 <- rexp(n, lambda1)
  data.frame(x1, x2 = rgamma(n, (runif(n) > 1 - theta/(1 + lambda1*theta)) + 1, lambda2*(1 + lambda1*theta*x1)))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your response. Initially I was working on using this same approach but I got a complicated distribution which I couldn’t figure the type of distribution of the x2 conditioned on x1. Could you please help me with the theoretical part of your approach? I would appreciate that a lot. Thank you.

Comment: It would be easier to follow with LaTeX on Cross Validated, but I did my best. See the update.

Comment: The algebra is correct as you said. I am a bit confused on the last part of the codes, thus; x2 = rgamma(n, (runif(n) > wExp/(wExp + wGamma)) + 1, D).  Why did you consider runif(n) been greater than the fraction of the weights? And also why +1? That part seem a little confusing. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Consider the case where `wExp = 0.3` and `wGamma = 0.9`. For ~75% of the samples, `runif(n) > wExp/(wExp + wGamma)` will return `TRUE`, and the shape parameter will be `TRUE + 1 = 2`. For other ~25% of the samples, `runif(n) > wExp/(wExp + wGamma)` will return `FALSE`, and the shape parameter will be `FALSE + 1 = 1`. A gamma with a shape parameter of 1 can be formulated as an exponential distribution.

Comment: The algebra you mentioned looks correct, I’m just wondering if we still need to consider ‘C’ in the denominator (presented in the updated part) because, in ‘A’, we already have ‘C’ defined in its denominator. Also, the conditional density distribution which I derived can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A6BjcUj7eGcoMZl1JBVeurIfYGH7M3d2/view?usp=sharing   whereas you mentioned “The distribution of x2 conditioned on x1 is a gamma mixture”. Please correct me if I’m wrong. Thank you

Comment: `C` is in the denominator of both `A` and `B` (and, consequently, both `wExp` and `wGamma`), so it cancels out. You can check the equivalency of the two functions presented by setting a common seed before calling each.